# PHP Login Script with Ajax loading Header on same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sqlite, forms

I have a PHP login script that I want to execute with ajax. The PHP script takes the user to a page if successful but according to the ajax request I am using, the `header` location also loads in the `$('.logresult') div` how do I do it such that it goes to the `header` location when successful and shows the error in the `$('logresult')` if not. Below are my codes:

**Ajax Request**

```
$('#submit_log').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#loginForm').serialize(),
    form = $('#loginForm');
    $.post($(form).attr("action"), data, function(data) {
        $('.logresult').html(data);
    })
});
```

**PHP Login Script**

```
session_start();
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();

if(isset($_POST['log_name']) && isset($_POST['log_password'])) {
    $username = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['log_name']);
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['log_password']);

    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = ?");
    $sql->bindParam(1, $username, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $ret = $sql->execute();

    $count = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as COUNT FROM users WHERE uname = ?");
    $count->bindParam(1, $password, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $count_ret = $count->execute();

    if (count($count_ret) == 1)
    {
        while ($row = $ret->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
        {
            $id = $row['userid'];
            $regas = $row['regas'];
            $uemail = $row['uemail'];
            $pword = $row['pword'];

            if (password_verify($password, $pword))
            {


              $_SESSION['log_id'] = $id;
              $_SESSION['log_name'] = $username;
              $_SESSION['regas'] = $regas;
              $_SESSION['uemail'] = $uemail;
              header("Location: index.php?log_id=$id");
              exit();
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Information incorrect";
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am guessing the issue is `$('.logresult').html(data);` but don't really know how to fix this (am new to ajax generally). Thanks

Comment: Why use ajax to submit the data if you use header to redirect

Answer (score 0):

simply don't use ajax if you want to change the location. ajax usage is mostly when you don't want a page reload. in most cases ajax response is a json and handle the response with javascript.

Comment: Thanks. But what if want to to say the incorrect username or password without refreshing

Comment: in this case you response a json with a code and message. then with javascript check the response code. for example if it was 404, show a popup message to user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the location of the page after success, it is doable via your ajax, I do it all the time. It is also not unusual to have a site use ajax and redirect on success, I have seen it a lot. In your php, instead of doing:

```
header("Location: index.php?log_id=$id");
exit();
```

To keep it simple to work with your existing script, you can send back javascript:

```
die("<script>window.location='http://www.example.com/index.php?log_id={$id}';</script>");
```

If I were to redo what you have, I would receive json instead in the form of actions/instructions from the PHP and have the javascript in the success interpret the instructions, but that is more complex.